# Describe monotonicity of $f(x)=|\log (x+1)|$ at $x=0$

Tags: monotone-functions

The function is $$f(x)=\begin {cases} \log (x+1) & x\ge 0 \\ -\log(x+1) & x <0 \end {cases}$$

So
$$f’(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x+1} & x\ge 0 \\ \frac{-1}{x+1} & x<0 \end {cases}$$

Now $f’(0) = 1 > 0$, so it should be strictly increasing

From the graph, it’s clear that the function is non monotonous at $x=0$. I also know that I am making a very trivial error, but I am confused about the cases when $x=0$

I am aware that the function is non differentiable at $x=0$, but discontinuous points are accepted when defining monotonicity

I have a very conceptual problem regarding this, so I chose a simple example.

If $f’(0)$ simply does not exist, then why do we consider discontinuous points?

Comment: When you define $f(x)$, you need to have the cases be $\log(x+1)$ if $\log(x+1)\geq 0$ and $-\log(x+1)$ if $\log(x+1)<0$. It doesn't make sense the way you have it defined now.

Comment: @CSquared I think it can be defined in terms of $x$, since$ \log y <0$ for $y\in (0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Monotonicity does not depend on differentiability. A function can be monotone without being differentiable. This is because the definition of $f(x)$ to be monotone increasing, for example, is $\forall x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb R , \frac{ f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1 - x_2} \ge 0$, where $x_1 \ne x_2$. This does not require differentiability at all.

However, if $f'(x) \ge 0$, then $f(x)$ is monotone increasing. (Remove all the equalities and you get the strict case.) This theorem enables us to **determine** whether a function is monotone, by inspecting its derivative. This method fails if this function has no derivative at all. So monotonicity is not affected, it is the *link* between the derivative and monotonicity that gets cut off.

Comment: So if basically, if $f’(a)$ does not exist, there is no mathematical way to tell if the function is monotone or not

Comment: @Aditya Of course there is. Simply verify that $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\ge 0$, as said in the answer. In fact, you ought to have learnt this method **before** you even heard of derivatives.

Comment: Right, so derivatives can’t be used. Out of curiosity, what would you plug in for $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: @Aditya I can't choose which. I have to plug in all possible values of $x_1, x_2$, and verify that inequality for all of them.

Comment: Then how would you determine the function is not monotonous if graphing isn’t possible?

Comment: It depends on what you know about $f(x)$.

Comment: In the context of this question. How would you know that the function is not monotonous, assuming graphing is not allowed